# How to add a limit on a text-size change button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, text, font-size

I am working on a webpage aimed for the elderly. I have two buttons that allow the webpage's text to either make it bigger or smaller. However, I need to put a limit on how big & small the text can change so it does not mess up the webpage.

From the text's starting point (which is 12px), it should be able to be enlarged **twice**, otherwise it'll go off the page. Also from the starting point, the text should be able to decrease in size **once**. I am new to Javascript so I am unsure on how to do this. Any help would be appriciated!

My current code:

```
<script>
function resizeText(multiplier) {
  if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
    document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
  }
  document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
}</script>

<input id="plusText" alt="Increase text size" value="Letter size +" type="button" onclick="resizeText(1) "/>
<input id="minusText" alt="Decrease text size" value="Letter size &#8211" type="button" onclick="resizeText(-1) "/>
```

Comment: Off-topic, but shouldn't you let the browser handle page zooming and focus on making your content readable at any zoom level instead of taking these matters into your own hands?

Comment: I have thought about this, yes. However, this webpage is aimed towards an elderly crowd, who may not be all that technologically inclined. My employer wanted buttons on the webpage for easy access to users (he was very nitpicky about it too). I understand that it is impossible to have browser zoom buttons on the webpage, so enlarging text was the only other reasonable thing I could think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my approach:

Modification:

User can increase font size maximum **'`2em`'** and minimum **'`1em`'**

Modified Function:

```
function resizeText(multiplier) {
  if (document.body.style.fontSize == "" || parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) <= 1 ) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = "1.2em";    
  }

  if ( document.body.style.fontSize == '2em' && multiplier > 0 ) {
        return false;
  } else {
    document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
  }


}
```

```js
function resizeText(multiplier) {
  if (document.body.style.fontSize == "" || parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) <= 1 ) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = "1.2em";    
  }

  if ( document.body.style.fontSize == '2em' && multiplier > 0 ) {
        return false;
  } else {
    document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
  }
  
  console.log(document.body.style.fontSize);
}
```

```html
<input id="plusText" alt="Increase text size" value="Letter size +" type="button" onclick="resizeText(1) "/>
<input id="minusText" alt="Decrease text size" value="Letter size &#8211" type="button" onclick="resizeText(-1) "/>



<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
```